# Create a customized @State in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I can create a basic @State as shown below. There's one thing super important missing, which is the content of `update`, is there any way to mimic a real @State?

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct MyStates:DynamicProperty{
    init(wrappedValue:String){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(wrappedValue, forKey: "myString")
    }
    
    var wrappedValue:String{
        nonmutating set{UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "myString")}
        get{UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "myString") ?? ""}
    }
    
    var projectedValue:Binding<String>{
        Binding<String>(
            get:{String(self.wrappedValue)},
            set:{
                self.wrappedValue = $0
        }
        )
    }
    
    func update() {
        print("render again")
```

Comment: You need something that already uses DynamicProperty to signal SwiftUI, there are a ton of tutorials online on how to create custom property wrappers. AppStorage already handles UserDefaults

Comment: yes, but how to implement  `update` within my code to render SwiftUI view?  property wrapper does not matter with it.

Comment: As lorem ipsum said, "You need something that already uses `DynamicProperty` to signal SwiftUI". You would call `update` of *that* `DynamicProperty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update()` does not render the `View`, SwiftUI does, you have to play by SwiftUI’s rules.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MyStates:DynamicProperty{
    @AppStorage("myString") var myString: String = “”
    init(wrappedValue:String){
        myString = wrappedValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue:String{
        nonmutating set{myString = new value}
        get{myString}
    }
    
    var projectedValue:Binding<String>{
        Binding<String>(
            get:{String(self.wrappedValue)},
            set:{
                self.wrappedValue = $0
        }
        )
    }
    
    func update() {
        print("rendered")
```

Comment: I think the key point here is `DynamicProperty`. Once we have this, Any change of within `MyStates` will tell our UI View to invalidate again. And the purpose of `update` here is just kind of side effect,.

Answer (score 0):

`update` is where you read from your external storage and update vars on the struct from their initial value that the struct was init with to their latest value from the external storage, e.g.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MyStates: DynamicProperty {

    var value: String

    class Observer: ObservableObject {
         let objectWillChange = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.myString, options: .new)
    }
    @StateObject private var observer = Observer()

    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        value = wrappedValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        nonmutating set{
            UserDefaults.standard.myString = newValue
        }
        get {
            value
        }
    }
    
    mutating func update() {
        if let v = UserDefaults.standard.myString {
            value = v
        }
    }
}

public extension UserDefaults {
    @objc dynamic var myString: String? {
        get { string(forKey: "myString") }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: "myString") }
    }
}
```